# Canvas game separation of the triangle

Tags: canvas, kineticjs, konvajs

http://joxi.ru/NDrlaKnT01RamP
The goal is to ensure that the user can visually divided into equal parts triangle. The resulting figure should be equal in size with an accuracy of 10%.
How to implement it on the canvas? Can someone tell?

Comment: Did you try something in order to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes of course. I got to create from one side to another side of the triangle line. Get the point, assign points to an array of points of each line.
My main problem is that I can not draw the resulting figures after the separation, in order to calculate their area.   I do not know how to draw the points now like this: http://joxi.ru/j1A5bL4iGPdDrE

Comment: in the example quoted in your comment, the initial triangle is not splitted into two triangles,  but rather splitted by a line into one line and one polygon. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @GameAlchemist, They are letting the player subdivide an original triangle into 2 pieces--2 new polygons. The player wins if the 2 new polygons are within 10% the same area as each other. Normally I would hesitate to answer non-code-questions with a code-answer, but what they want is trivially easy in KonvaJS (formerly KineticJS) :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1: Drawing the original and subdivided polygons:**

To draw any polygon shape (3 sides triangles, 4,5,6+ sided polygons) you can use the `Konvas.Line`. Just feed it the points of each vertex on the polygon and you're done!

```
// points[] are the vector points of any polygon

var newTriangle = new Konva.Line({
  points: [220,220,295,140,375,220,222,220],
  stroke: 'black',
  closed : true,
});
```

Here's an example that shows your original triangle and the 2 new shapes divided from the original triangle (your 3 & 4 sided polygons):

[image]

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 400,
  height: 350
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var originalTriangle = new Konva.Line({
  points: [12,220,195,40,375,220,12,220],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 7,
  closed : true
});
layer.add(originalTriangle);

var newQuadrilateral = new Konva.Line({
  points: [12,220,195,40,295,140,220,220,12,220],
  fill: 'gold',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 3,
  closed : true,
  draggable:true,
});
layer.add(newQuadrilateral);

var newTriangle = new Konva.Line({
  points: [220,220,295,140,375,220,222,220],
  fill: 'green',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 3,
  closed : true,
  draggable:true,
});
layer.add(newTriangle);

layer.draw();
```

```css
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/0.9.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<h4>The new shapes are draggable (yellow and green)</h4>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Part 2: Calculating the areas of the subdivided polygons**

You indicate you have the math to calculate the subdivided areas handled, but just in case here's a link: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon#Finding_the_Area_of_Irregular_Polygons_sub

Comment: User must devide the triangel and after that I must calculate the areas. Your answer is not what I need.

Comment: I understand that...but...Surely you don't want me to take all your fun by coding your entire project!  All that's left for you to do is listen for a couple of mouse events and plug those mouse points into my solution. After all this is **your project!** :-}}